# ReactJs: can't access object element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In componentDidMount (), I get the data and pass it to the state.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const url = fetch('http://localhost:8000/posts/')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({ data: response });
        })
}
```

Next I try to get the data of `this.state.data[0].id`
In this case, I get the error

> TypeError: cannot read property 'id' of undefined

But if I try to get data through `this.state.data[0]`, then an object comes in, where there is a property `id`

Comment: Try this.state.data.length>0?this.state.data[0].id:'' "

Comment: Probably you are trying to access the data *before* it comes back from the server. Rohit's suggestion should help.

Comment: how does your initial state look like?

Comment: Can you post the whole component?

Comment: Please show a **complete** code example. Where do you use `this.state.data[0].id`? Is it in your `render()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching your data from a remote source and this fetch operation is asynchronous. In the initial render of your app you don't have this data yet.`componentDidMount` triggers the fetch and your data lands in your app. So, you should use a conditional rendering as recommended in the comments. Here is a simple example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(posts => {
        this.setState({ posts });
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { posts } = this.state;
    return <div>{!!posts.length && posts[0].title}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

And with a little enhancement. Because I'm pretty sure that you won't use a single data item in your app. As a future reference, you can use this simple logic. A better approach would be refactoring this code and writing a separate `Post` component.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(posts => {
        this.setState({ posts });
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { posts } = this.state;
    if (!posts.length) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    return (
      <div>
        {posts.map(post => (
          <div key={post.id}>
            <p>{post.title}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```